# How many roots does $(1+z^3)^8 = (1 + z^4)^6$ have?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I got stuck on this question:

**How many roots does $(1+z^3)^8 = (1 + z^4)^6$ have? (including complex roots and roots with multiplicity)**

My attempt at a solution:

First we can write the equation as:

$$(1+z^3)^8 - (1 + z^4)^6 = 0$$
We can then factor $(1+z^3)$

$$(z+1)^8(z^2-z+1)^8 - (1 + z^4)^6 = 0$$

But I am stuck here, the expression $(1+z^4)$ cannot easily be factored, but it should have 4 complex roots. I think there should be a simpler way to solve this question...

Comment: The difference between the LHS and the RHS is a polynomial with degree $21$. How many roots (accounted with multiplicity) do you expect?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, 21 roots are correct, but how do you see that the difference is 21?

Comment: On the LHS, the exponents are $24,21,18,\ldots$, on the  RHS they are $24,20,16,\ldots$. The term $z^{21}$ does not cancel out, so the degree of the difference is $21$.

Comment: @Lukas Think about the coefficients of the $z^{24}$ terms (they cancel). There are no $z^{23}$ or $z^{22}$ terms, so the highest nonzero-coefficient term is $z^{21}$.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a polynomial equation of degree $21$, so there are $21$ roots, counted with multiplicities.

Comment: That is correct, please elaborate on how you see that this is of degree 21... That part I don't understand :)

Comment: Put everything on th left hand side, develop everything and regroup by powers of $z$, and you will find a polynomial of degree $21$. Obviously, you could try smarter things to show that there won't be powers of $z$ with exponent $>21$, but that's up to you.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense!

Comment: You're welcome !

Answer (score 0):

$(z^3+1)^8 = (z^4+1)^6$

$z^{24} + 8z^{21} + 28z^{18} + 56z^{15} + 70z^{12} + 56z^9 + 28z^6 + 8z^3 + 1 = z^{24} + 6z^{20} + 15z^{16} + 20z^{12} + 15z^8 + 6z^4 + 1$

$z^{24} + 8z^{21} + 28z^{18} + 56z^{15} + 70z^{12} + 56z^9 + 28z^6 + 8z^3 + 1 - z^{24} - 6z^{20} - 15z^{16} - 20z^{12} - 15z^8 - 6z^4 - 1 = 0$

$z^3(8z^{18} - 6z^{17} + 28z^{15} - 15z^{13} + 56z^{12} + 50z^9 + 56z^6 - 15z^5 + 28z^3 - 6z + 8) = 0$

$z^3(4z^6 - 3z^5 + 6z^3 - 3z + 4)(2z^{12} + 4z^9 + 3z^8 + 6z^6 + 3z^4 + 4z^3 + 2)$

Cannot be factored further, but we can try to solve it from there:

- $z^3 = 0 \Rightarrow \sqrt[3]{z^3} = \sqrt[3]{0} \Rightarrow z = 0$
- $4z^6 - 3z^5 + 6z^3 - 3z + 4 = 0$ has 6 complex roots (three pairs of complex conjugates)
- $2z^{12} + 4z^9 + 3z^8 + 6z^6 + 3z^4 + 4z^3 + 2 = 0$ has 12 complex roots (six pairs of complex conjugates)

The equation has 19 roots.

Comment: "including (..) roots with multiplicity", so you should count $z^3$ three times to get to 21 total